# How to print all the text inside <div> tag which is inside a <li> python selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Hi all I want to print a list of names inside a `<div>` tag and the `<div>` tag is inside a `<li>` tag below I will attach the HTML snippet. Please help me to print it out.

In the below snippet, there is a class `linkedAccountUserName` like that I have 6 names one below another I want to print the names.

I am using python selenium to get it.

[image]

here is the website snippet I will click the profile icon and list all the names available below Linked account
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't put any html code, I couldn't test this code. Here is my assumed html code snippet and it is called 'test_html.html':

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li class="item">
      <div class="linkedAccountUserName">user1</div>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <div class="linkedAccountUserName">user2</div>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <div class="linkedAccountUserName">user3</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is code to get the names. I tested it and it prints:
user1
user2
user3

```
from selenium import webdriver
browserProfile = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
browserProfile.add_experimental_option('prefs', {'intl.accept_languages': 'en,en_US'})
browser = webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver", options=browserProfile)
browser.get("file:///home/mahsa/test_html.html")
names = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('div[class=\'linkedAccountUserName\']')
for i in range(len(names)):
  print(names[i].text)
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_css_selector'


This the code i am using
main = driver.find_element_by_class_name("userMenuControl").click()
names = main.find_elements_by_css_selector('div[class=\'linkedAccountUserName\']')
for i in range(len(names)):
  print(names[i].text)

Comment: @dusky-dood can you please send the html snippet so I can test the written code?

Comment: are you available in instagram so i can send the snippet and explain]

Comment: main = driver.find_element_by_class_name("userMenuControl").click() - this will click a a icon and the icon give a listbox in that list box html we have to fetch the names

Comment: @dusky-dood I have updated my answer. Please look at it and test if it works.

Comment: The html is available in a dropdown icon from a top right corner. If we click the icon and after that, we can give inspect element in the dropdown box

Comment: Its working bro i made an issue. How to filter the text if it has a list like <div class="linkedAccountUserName"> 3 , user</div>

Comment: Instead of `find_elements_by_css_selector()` use `find_element_by_css_selector()`. It gives you only the first element matches the condition.

Comment: I am asking like 



 <ul>
    <li class="item">
      <div class="linkedAccountUserName">1 , user</div>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <div class="linkedAccountUserName">2 , user</div>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <div class="linkedAccountUserName">3 , user</div>
    </li>
  </ul>

Comment: the output will be 1, user  2, user  3, user 

but i want to print the only user that is after comma text

Comment: @DuskyDood Your question is string processing. For example if you have "firstname, lastname" and you want only the "lastname" part, you should do this: `"firstname, lastname".split(",")[1]`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should find the `<li>` tag with the class `item`. After that you should iterate over all `<div>` items. I do not have your code to reproduce it, but it will be somthing like this, where soup is the `HTML` obteined with [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/):

```py
#Getting the data 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
#Printing the data you want
li = soup.find('div',attrs={'class':'item'})
divs = li.findAll("div")
for div in divs:
  print(div.text)
```

Comment: I am not using bs4
I am using selenium and driver
The below code contains the li tag and div tag
main = driver.find_element_by_class_name("userMenuControl").click()

Comment: you can use selenium and bs4. I have updated my response. At least is how I work when I use selenium

Comment: This Html i will get in a drop-down menu from navigation bar so i cant parse it